# Quorum BlockChain Issue

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, quorum

I have setup a Quorum blockchain 2.0 server, with RAFT based consensus. As quorum chain in not part of version 2.0.
The blockchain server works good for some time and after a successful run of 5-6 hours, it just stops mining any more blocks. This has happen o me 3 and to my other team mates.
does the current version of quorum have a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

How many nodes are you set up?
Raft require n/2 + 1 node healthy to the elected miner. 
Please check node role after attaching geth with following command

```
raft.role
```

Is there any minter. If yes then you need to restart blockchain.
else You don't have n/2 + 1 healthy.